# how to remove google maps control

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i am implementing google maps on my website, but i want to remove satellite and map options from my maps which is shown on right top, also pan controls.this is my code,

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
            center: center,
            zoom: 8,
            maptypecontrol :false,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP 

        });
```

Can we do this???

Answer (score 13, accepted):

have a look at the documentation http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/controls.html#DisablingDefaults

the option should be

```
disableDefaultUI: true
```

Comment: @refhat yes it also removes the streetview controls. See the documentation

Answer (score 4):

Just set `mapTypeControl` option to false:

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    ...
    mapTypeControl: false
});
```

If you need some specific setting of the maptype control, look at the [mapTypeControlOptions](http://code.google.com/intl/cs/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MapTypeControlOptions). For example:

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    ...
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
        mapTypeIds: [ // array of availabe map types
            google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        ],
        style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [LIVE DEMO](http://www.svennerberg.com/examples/google_maps_3/properties.php) of how to customize the google maps properties for your requirements.